# input type data change the select ng-options data using angularjs

Tags: angularjs

i know how to bind select to the input text. but i want know reverse order of this
if i enter the data in input field it effects on the select ng-options data 
automatically.

```
<select ng-options="item.productcode as item.productname  for item in getproductList" ng-model="lining.barcode">
<option value="">--Select Product--</option></select>
<input type="text" ng-model="lining.barcode">
```

I want to know reverse order. Enter in input field auto matically select the ng-options

please give the solution.

Comment: as far as i know you dont have to do anything for that, angular works on 2 way binding, which means all references will be impacted when specific model changes. so your current code should work fine without doing anything

Comment: refer this jsfiddle,http://jsfiddle.net/Td2NZ/1595/ .try changing the dropdown value and text field to see what happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change your data(namings).
Here is an functional example.

Markup:

```
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <select ng-options="item as item.productname for item in getproductList track by item.productcode" ng-model="lining">
    <option value="">--Select Product--</option></select>
    <input type="text" ng-model="lining.productcode" >
</body>
```

Code:

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
  .controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.getproductList = [{
      productcode: 1,
      productname: "name1"
    }, {
      productcode: 2,
      productname: "name2"
    }];
}]);
```

Working [**plunker**](https://plnkr.co/edit/ViLDyYlrOmti6QzOgaBt?p=preview) for product code.

**Edit**

The example above track by the productcode. If you want to write on the text box the name instead the just modify markup like this

```
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <select ng-options="item as item.productname for item in getproductList track by item.productname" ng-model="lining">
    <option value="">--Select Product--</option></select>
    <input type="text" ng-model="lining.productname" >
</body>
```

Working [**plunker**](https://plnkr.co/edit/lgvhCUW3tM7nMT24xAC8?p=preview) for productname.

Comment: Thanks for your Answer.@jose  Rocha